# Make selectionbox unclickable

Tags: jquery, html

Consider this form:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="rad" id='A' value="A"><label for="A">A</label><br>       
    <input type="radio" name="rad" id='B' value="B"><label for="B">B</label>
    <select name='choice'>
        <option selected disabled>Make a choice</option>
        <option value='1'>Choice 1</option>
        <option value='2'>Choice 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

If the user clicks radiobutton A, he has the free choice what to select in the selectionbox.
If the user clicks radiobutton B, then I would like to make the selectionbox unclickable and it should select Choice 1.

How can I accomplish this with jQuery? My initial thought was to disable the selection box when radiobutton B is active, but then the form won't send the value of the field **choice** since it is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, you can't directly disable the select as then its value is not sent in any requests.

To achieve this you can hook to the `change` event of the radio inputs and check the chosen value. If `B` is selected then you can use set `pointer-events: none` on the select and force its value to `1`. Try this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    var $radio = $(this), $select = $('select');

    if ($radio.val() == 'A') {
        $select.removeClass('no-pointer');
    }
    else {
        $select.val('1').addClass('no-pointer');
    }
})
```

```css
.no-pointer {
    pointer-events: none
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/5nj9gnqh/)

Note that `pointer-events` is not supported in IE10 or lower. If you need to support older browsers then you could instead disable the `select` and use a hidden field to send the value when the `form` is submit.

Comment: No problem, glad to help